# ¿Activar y desactivar un boton segun seleccion en checklistbox MS Visual Basic?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2017

Cordial saludo compañeros, resulta que tengo un CRUD en MS Visual Basic, conectado a una base de datos llamado cotización, funciona perfectamente, utilizo un checklistbox que se llena con los datos de la bd y también lo uso para seleccionar los registros a los que les quiero aplicar el actualizar o el eliminar, lo que ahora trato de hacer es algunas validaciones de usuario y entre ellas, que el botón de actualizar y eliminar estén desactivados al abrir el formulario, esto lo hago usando las siguientes sentencias en el load del formulario:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        btnactualizar.Enabled = False
        btneliminar.Enabled = False
    End Sub
```

Ahora lo que trato de hacer es que si selecciono un contenido del checklistbox , se habiliten estos botones y si quito esta selección se vuelvan a desactivar. use esta sentencia en el checklistbox:

```
Private Sub checklistestudios_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checklistestudios.SelectedIndexChanged

If checklistestudios.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then


            btnactualizar.Enabled = True
            btneliminar.Enabled = True
        ElseIf checklistestudios.SelectedIndex < 0 Then
            btnactualizar.Enabled = False
            btneliminar.Enabled = False
        End If
    End Sub
```

Funciona al momento de seleccionar algo en el checklistbox, activa los botones, pero si quito la selección los botones siguen activos y lo que busco es que ese desactiven si no hay nada chuleado en el checklistbox, ¿como podría hacerlo?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa el ItemCheck de tu CheckListBox y haz 3 comparaciones:

- si seleccion > 1 entonces activa los botones
- si seleccion = 1 y desactiva el check entonces desactiva los botones
- Si seleccion =0 y activa un check entonces activa los botones

Ejemplo :

```
Private Sub CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.ItemCheck
    If CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count > 1 Then
        btnactualizar.Enabled = True
        btneliminar.Enabled = True
    End If

    If CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count = 1 And e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked Then
        btnactualizar.Enabled = False
        btneliminar.Enabled = False
    End If

    If CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count = 0 And e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked Then
        btnactualizar.Enabled = True
        btneliminar.Enabled = True
    End If

End Sub
```

En este caso tendrías que cambiar CheckedListBox1 por checklistestudios

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo.